Optimizing GPU Subdivision of Icosahedron in Compute Shader to Prevent Driver Timeouts
I am working on a C# script that uses a compute shader to generate a file containing a list of vertices and indices representing an icosphere. I use the compute shader to compute vertex positions and the indices, which I then read back in C# and save vertices and indices in a file.I was able to write a working code, but as I increase the subdivision level over 4 it crashes and I am getting a "detected driver timeout" from my amd GPU. I believe the solution would be to spread out the computation across the GPU, but I am not really sure how to proprly increase local size or parallelize the subdivision process better so that each triangle can be processed independently without conflicts.
Here is the compute shader:
#version 450

layout(local_size_x = 1, local_size_y = 1, local_size_z = 1) in;

struct Triangle {
    int index1;
    int index2;
    int index3;
};

layout(std430, binding = 0) buffer VerticesBuffer {
    vec4 vertices[];
};

layout(std430, binding = 1) buffer TrianglesBuffer {
    Triangle triangles[];
};

layout(std430, binding = 2) buffer OutputVerticesBuffer {
    vec4 outputVertices[];
};

layout(std430, binding = 3) buffer OutputIndicesBuffer {
    int outputIndices[];
};

layout(std430, binding = 4) buffer CountBuffer {
    int counts[2]; // 0 = vertex count, 1 = triangle count
};

// Global counts for vertices and triangles
int vertexCount = 12; // Initial vertex count for the icosahedron
int triangleCount = 20; // Initial triangle count for the icosahedron

int subdivisionLevel = 6; // Set this to desired subdivision level

void GenerateIcosahedron() {
    float phi = (1.0 + sqrt(5.0)) / 2.0;
    float a = 1.0;
    float b = phi;

    vec4 rawVertices[12] = {
        vec4(-a, b, 0, 1.0), vec4(a, b, 0, 1.0), vec4(-a, -b, 0, 1.0), vec4(a, -b, 0, 1.0),
        vec4(0, -a, b, 1.0), vec4(0, a, b, 1.0), vec4(0, -a, -b, 1.0), vec4(0, a, -b, 1.0),
        vec4(b, 0, -a, 1.0), vec4(b, 0, a, 1.0), vec4(-b, 0, -a, 1.0), vec4(-b, 0, a, 1.0)
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i) {
        vertices[i] = vec4(normalize(rawVertices[i].xyz), 1.0);
        outputVertices[i] = vertices[i];
    }

    Triangle triData[20] = {
        {5, 11, 0}, {1, 5, 0}, {7, 1, 0}, {10, 7, 0},
        {11, 10, 0}, {9, 5, 1}, {4, 11, 5}, {2, 10, 11},
        {6, 7, 10}, {8, 1, 7}, {4, 9, 3}, {2, 4, 3},
        {6, 2, 3}, {8, 6, 3}, {9, 8, 3}, {5, 9, 4},
        {11, 4, 2}, {10, 2, 6}, {7, 6, 8}, {1, 8, 9}
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
        triangles[i] = triData[i];
        if (subdivisionLevel == 0) {
            outputIndices[3 * i] = triData[i].index1;
            outputIndices[3 * i + 1] = triData[i].index2;
            outputIndices[3 * i + 2] = triData[i].index3;
        }
    }

    counts[0] = 12; // Initial vertex count
    counts[1] = 20; // Initial triangle count
}

int GetMidpointIndex(int index1, int index2) {
    vec3 midpoint = normalize((vertices[index1].xyz + vertices[index2].xyz) * 0.5);
    for (int i = 0; i < vertexCount; ++i) {
        if (distance(vertices[i].xyz, midpoint) < 0.001) {
            return i; // Midpoint already exists
        }
    }
    vertices[vertexCount] = vec4(midpoint, 1.0);
    outputVertices[vertexCount] = vec4(midpoint, 1.0);
    vertexCount++;
    return vertexCount - 1;
}

void SubdivideTriangle(int idx) {
    int i1 = triangles[idx].index1;
    int i2 = triangles[idx].index2;
    int i3 = triangles[idx].index3;

    int m1 = GetMidpointIndex(i1, i2);
    int m2 = GetMidpointIndex(i2, i3);
    int m3 = GetMidpointIndex(i3, i1);

    // Replace existing triangle with the first new one
    triangles[idx] = Triangle(i1, m1, m3);

    // Append new triangles to the list
    triangles[triangleCount++] = Triangle(i2, m2, m1);
    triangles[triangleCount++] = Triangle(i3, m3, m2);
    triangles[triangleCount++] = Triangle(m1, m2, m3);
}

void main() {
    GenerateIcosahedron();

    if (subdivisionLevel > 0) {
        int initialTriangleCount = triangleCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < subdivisionLevel; ++i) {
            int countAtThisLevel = triangleCount;
            for (int j = 0; j < countAtThisLevel; ++j) {
                SubdivideTriangle(j);
            }
        }
    }

    counts[0] = vertexCount;
    counts[1] = triangleCount * 3; // Multiply by 3 to get the total number of indices
}

I tried to increase local_size_x but with no result or receiving messed up vertices and indices. How can I modify the compute shader to better utilize the GPU and prevent timeouts?
